# How to call onclick function in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jquery calendar code like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calTwo').jCal({
        day: new Date( (new Date()).setMonth( (new Date()).getMonth() + 2 ) ),
        days: 7,
        showMonths: 1,
        monthSelect:    true
    });
});
</script>
```

And in my body contest as follows

```
<body>
<span id="calTwo"></span>
</body>
```

The above code is working fine but my requirement is instead of using span id tag i need to use text field and adjacent to the text field one calendar image. By clicking on that image calendar should get displayed, and whatever the date i have selected that should be shown in the text field.

I am new to Jquery and no idea how to implement this feature Any help.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<input id="calTwo" /> <img src="..." id="calTwoIcon" />

<script>
$('#calTwoIcon').click(function() {
    $('#calTwo').focus();
});
</script>
```

Is that what you were looking for? I just placed an image and assigned a click event that upon getting called will focus the calendar input which should bring up the calendar. Alternatively you could do `$('#calTwo').trigger('click');`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jCal, you could also use jQuery UI [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

HTML:

```
Date: <input id="calTwo" type="text"></input>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calTwo').datepicker().option({"setDate": new Date()});
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YQ7k8/
The example is ugly because jsfiddle doesn't have jQuery UI css. Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ to see how it might look with the right theme.